# oreintation problems in a section table view based app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have few text fields in sectioned table view. When i rotate the view gets rotated according to the orientation but not getting filled up according to the screen. For instance i have set the width using CGRectMake method for portrait as 70.0 but when it is turned to left the size of the text box is the same and not getting expanded according to the width.

I have the widths setup in my tableview code according to the orientation. Please tell me how to reload the tableview after the orientation change or what is the way to make the CGRectMake to change automatically based on the orientation for each component in table view.